# Numpy: how to add / join slice objects?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, indexing

For a `2*N x 2*N` array `x`, I'd like to swap rows `[0:N]` with rows `[N:2*N]` in a particular way, namely, the question I have is, if there is a 'built-in' way of 'adding / joining' slice objects to achieve this? I.e. something like:

```
x[N:2*N + 0:N,:]
```

although, the preceding does something different.

Certainly I could do things like `vstack((x[N:2*N,:],x[0:N,:]))`, which is not really what I'm looking for, or `x[[i for i in range(N)]+[i for i in range(N,2*N)],:]`, which probably is slow.

Comment: You should add an example input and its expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`numpy.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), which "translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis". It allows you to perform more complex slices along the first axis - you can concatenate multiple slices with commas: `np.r_[5:10, 100:200:10, 15, 20, 0:5]`.

For example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 2
>>> x = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
>>> x[np.r_[N:2*N, 0:N]]
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7]])
```

And in this specific case, you could also just [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) it:

```py
>>> np.roll(x, N, axis=0)
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess `r_[N:2*N, 0:N]` is somehow identical to `[i for i in range(N)]+[i for i in range(N,2*N)]` (which I was mentioning in my question already), or `range(N,2*N)+range(N)`, or anything similar, which concatenates the index range `N:2*N` and `0:N` into a single range. So it remains to be seen which is fastest. Finally, is `roll()` comparable to actual indexing regarding speed?

Comment: With multiple slices you have to concatenate somewhere, either before indexing or after. There's no magical compiled multi slice notation.  'roll' uses the same method(s).

Comment: @Mark if you're after performance, it seems like `roll` and `vstack` are much faster than using index ranges (which makes sense).